# Web Map not defaulting to original extent

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I built a webmap in ArcGIS Online using the ArcGIS Web AppBuilder and deployed it to my organizations web server, [here](http://nwrpcmaps.nwrpc.com/bb/).

Everything seems to be working except for one thing. If I refresh the map or go browse somewhere else on the internet and come back to the web map URL is doesn't default, or reset, the initial extent of the web map (which was configured to in the webappbuilder on arcgis online). the map remains focused wherever I left off even after a refresh or clearing of the browsers cache.

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried to set the initial extent as per [these instructions](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/map-tab.htm)? Try setting the option _Use Web Map's Default Extent_

Comment: Yeah, I set that up, but it only applies to the map's initial extent. Any time the web map URL is re-visited it remains wherever the end-user left off. It does not return to that specified initial extent. I cross-posted this question to Geonet and it appears ESRI is aware of the behavior and plans on fixing things somewhere down the line.